# django : multi database add databases dynamically

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, django-orm

I'm developing a project with django where **each user** is supposed to have **one database**.
**I found a way to do so :**
Fill the settings/dev.py with all databases (one per user)
Use the database router class to route the database to the models to the corresponding database (except the user model which will be redirected to a constant 'users' database of course because it is used to log in)

So when someone **creates an account** in our website and clicks the **verify** link sent by mail, it is supposed to q**uery the server** to run "manage.py create user", create a database for this user, change **settings/dev.py** to *add* the db to the **list** and finally perform a **migration** to create the db. Then, the user is redirected to the login page and is logged automatically with its credentials.

But i'm asking myself if **is the best way to do that** ?

Would we rather do the following ?

- **Create one app** (copy files + settings/dev.py) **for each user** and determine which app to use from an http header or a subdomain (user.site.com) or a port, etc.
- **Use one database** and create a user_id column in each table

Which one is the better for **performance**, **scalability**, **security** etc. ?

Thanks.

Comment: why does each user need a separate database?  it's a very unusual requirement, are you sure there's no other way to achieve what you actually want to do?

Comment: We target companies so we thought maybe it was better to have one database per user

Comment: but concretely what do you want to gain by using a db per company?  if you service them all from a single instance of a Django app then the 'sites framework' is probably what you want instead https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/

Comment: Each company has its clients and users (sellers, RH, admin) and if one db get hacked, at least the others are relatively safe.
The sites framework is for sharing resources between "sites" or in this case companies, isn't it ? It's not the same thing.

Comment: the companies are all running the same code though, so if one of them can be hacked they can all be hacked the same way.  there's no need to have separate dbs just to segregate ownership of clients, users etc, a foreign key to Company (or Site) model does that and is not going to complicate your life trying to bend django into an unusual pattern

Comment: I think it would be easier to generate whole django site per client from template than trying to stick all clients in single instance.

Comment: @Anentropic : Each company can also create its own users. Assume that I follow your model, how can i achieve that ? Is it by creating a column company_id in the auth_users table ?

Comment: @Ingaz : That's what we were doing before and i don't find it a good solution because we'll have to generate a site for each client. Managing app updates would be a mess as well as having multiple copies would be a little silly. Tell me if i'm wrong :) !
Plus, how can i identify a company's site ? Maybe by the subdomain or the port (with the port it won't be optimal though) ?

Comment: @AdamCherti: Are all your clients reside on single server? With site-per-client it's much easier to scale resources. App updates or sites are equal in complexity. About identification: I think subdomains are preferable

Comment: @Ingaz : For now, all the clients will be on a single server (i'm not certain about the futur though). Ok subdomains are good, you're right. But what if i want the user to authenticate in the main domain and being directly redirected to his subdomain by identifying that he belongs to this subdomain ? Do i have to create a common database listing all users of all dbs ? Wouldn't it be risky ?

Comment: _"we'll have to generate a site for each client. Managing app updates would be a mess as well as having multiple copies would be a little silly"_ I'm not sure what you mean here, but 'generating a site' (i.e. creating a record in the Sites model table, via Django admin or a data fixture etc) is much easier than all the workarounds you'd have to do to get a db per client. 'Managing updates' is the same either way - in both cases I understood we were talking about sharing a single Django project instance between all clients

Comment: We are sharing a single instance but wouldn't it be better for security purposes to have isolated dbs ?

Comment: I don't see a way to implement this with the sites module. It's for sites sharing one db

Comment: yes I'm suggesting to use a single db and the sites module.  I don't think it's inherently more secure using multiple dbs in this scenario.

Comment: But, I mean, the data is VERY important. Wouldn't it be better to isolate the dbs ?
If someone breaks into the data, there will be legal concerns and deep problems.